# Including files in C

Tags: c, include, math.h

I want to make a simple function involving `sqrt()`, `floor()` and `pow()`. So, I included `<math.h>`. When I try to use my function, my program says that `sqrt()` and `floor()` do not exist. I've triple checked my files and rewritten them, but it still gives the same error. Just to check if there was anything wrong with the `<math.h>` directory, I made another separate file that calculated the same thing and it worked. I am clueless right now. What am I doing wrong?

The code of the non functioning program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include "sumofsquares.h"

int sumofsquares(int x){
   int counter = 0;
   int temp = x;

   while(temp != 0){
      temp = temp - (int)pow(floor(sqrt(temp)), 2);
      counter ++;
   }
    return counter;
}
```

The working test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
   printf("%d", (int)pow(floor(sqrt(3)), 2));
}
```

the error is this

> /tmp/ccm0CMTL.o: In function sumofsquares':
>   /home/cs136/cs136Assignments/a04/sumofsquares.c:9: undefined reference
>   to sqrt' /home/cs136/cs136Assignments/a04/sumofsquares.c:9: undefined
>   reference to floor' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

I am using runC on a virtual Ubuntu OS to compile

Comment: What is the exact error ? How are you compiling your programs ?

Comment: @cnicutar: the error is this `/tmp/ccm0CMTL.o: In function `sumofsquares':
/home/cs136/cs136Assignments/a04/sumofsquares.c:9: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/cs136/cs136Assignments/a04/sumofsquares.c:9: undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
I am using runC on a virtual Ubuntu OS to complile.

Comment: That is a *linkage* problem, not an *include* problem. Check the answer by cnicutar.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably missing the `-lm` argument to `gcc`, required to link the math library. Try:

```
gcc ... <stuff> ... -lm
```

There are at least two C FAQs relevant to your problem:

- [14.3](http://c-faq.com/fp/libm.html)
- [13.26](http://c-faq.com/lib/libsearch.html)

Comment: I'm actually using RunC, so that does not apply to me. :(

Comment: "RunC is a simple (and somewhat crude) system that helps you use C++ as a scripting language under Unix." What we have here is evidence of that crudeness. You will need to figure out how to configure RunC to correctly link your script.